# How to make streaming with oboe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, streaming

I'm trying to do chat. I use only SQL, PHP and jQuery. In jQuery I use ajax with credentials with setTimeout after 1 second but in console I see too much requests. I would like to use streaming data. I'm trying to use oboe.js, below is my snippet:

```
  oboe({
   url: "http://coders.localhost/modules/fb-dialog/fb-content.php",
   withCredentials: true
}).node('data', function(data){
      console.log('You have a friend called', name);
   }).start(function(){
      interval = window.setInterval(function(){
         console.log('downloaded so far:', this.root());
      }.bind(this), 100);
   })
   .done(function(data){

   if(data.length>0){

   if($('.fb-content .media-body').children('div').last().hasClass('fb-rt')){

   $('.fb-content').append('<div class="media">\
         <div class="media-left">\
           <img class="face img-rounded" src="/pl/images/face.jpg">\
         </div>\
         <div class="media-body">\
         <div class="fb-lt"></div>\
       </div>\
     </div>');

   }

   $.each(data, function(index) {
   $('.fb-content .fb-lt').last().append('<div>' + this.message + '</div>');
   });

   $('.fb-content').animate({scrollTop: $('.fb-content').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);

   }

   });
```

on the server site works a PHP script which checks if is a new message from other user. If is it then returns JSON string. Something is wrong because jQuery does not cause a done method.

Comment: Does `oboe()` and `.start()` call return a `Promise`?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: What is return value of `.start()`?

Comment: .start() method returns: downloaded so far: Object {  }

Comment: `.start()` does not return a `Promise`?

Comment: no. In console or firebug return only this like above

Comment: `.done()` expects a `Promise`.

Comment: Can you show me an example?